# MS ODBC SQL Driver 13 version issue, How do I get/install a newer version?

Tags: drivers, installation, odbc, ms-sql

It simply seems that MS has not updated their download site to have the most up to date version of the version 13 ODBC driver.

When I download the MS SQL ODBC driver 13 from the Microsoft site, it installs version 13.0.1601.5 (noted as 2015.130.0.1601.5 in the ODBC Source Administrator).

However, if I install SQL Management Studio version 17.7 or higher, it installs the MS SQL ODBC driver 13 version 14.2002.4 (whish shows as version 2017.140.2002.4 in the ODBC Source Administrator).

The problem is that all of my workstations need the version 14.2002.4 installed.  The only way I have been able to do that is to install the SQL Management Studio on each workstation.  Aside from being a real time-suck, I really don't want the studio to be on the users workstations.

Since I have been unable to find the download of that driver as a standalone installation, does anybody know of a quicker way to just extract and install the updated ODBC driver?

NOTE:  I did download and install both MS SQL ODBC 13.1 and MS SQL ODBC 17 from the MS site, but again their version numbers differ.

Comment: Are you maybe referring to [Microsoft Command Line Utilities 14.0 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53591)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  No I am referring to the actual ODBC driver (MSODBCSQL13.dll).  But I may have figured it out.  It may be that the 13.1 version of the driver is indeed correct.  Just currently getting a test computer to validate that this is the answer

Comment: Just to update, installing 13.1 is still not the correct version to match what the SMSS installs.  13.1 installs as '2015.131.4414.46'

Comment: The version you're looking for is probably an intermediate version that was never released as stand-alone. I would guess that it's some variant in the range of versions 17, 17.1, 17.2 and 17.3 (beta), but only the last two can currently be officially downloaded from Microsoft. Possibly `14` may stand for `1.4` so might be closer to 17.1.

Comment: I think that you are correct.  For some reason it has caused a problem in my one customer's environment for one of our products.  Painful resolution is to install SMSS on each workstation ... not really what I wanted to do though.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a straightforward way to download only the the most recent version of the driver from the Microsoft website.

However, if you install the most recent SQL Management Studio on one machine, the installer for the most recent driver will be left under "C:\Windows\Installer".

Under that directory you will find a lot of installers, all with meaningless filenames, one of them should be the installer for whatever version of the ODBC driver you have installed on that machine.

To make it possible to find it easily, in Windows Explorer, right click on the columns, click on "More...", scroll down to Subject and tick the box, click OK. Now order by Subject and find "Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL server".

[Bit of a pain to find.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B4hA.png)

You can use this file to put the same version on each machine, and should save you from needing to install SQL Management Studio on each workstation.

Comment: This does not answer the authors question